# Matlab som access generated data and parameters

Tags: matlab, som

I'm completely new to Matlab and  I need some help.
I'm running a self-organising map with the Neural Networks toolbox.

It all works fine, I use

```
net = selforgmap([x y]);
net = train(net,mydata);
```

and then I get access to the nice plots.
However I'm interested in the actual numbers generated by the som. 
1)How do I access all the data underneath (is there a way to show all the vectors generated by the som package?
For example: 
2)how do I access the nodes weights? 
3)How do I access the list of cases and their allocated Best Matching Units?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have R2012, (and thus, I don't have 'selforgmap'), so this answer is potentially too general.

That said, I suspect that the variable 'net' is a a Neural Network object and if you type into the Command Window

```
net
```

Then you'll get a display of properties in that object (here's a shortened version of what I get)

```
net =

    Neural Network object:

    architecture:

         numInputs: 1
         numLayers: 2
       biasConnect: [1; 1]
      inputConnect: [1; 0]
      layerConnect: [0 0; 1 0]
     outputConnect: [0 1]

        numOutputs: 1  (read-only)
    numInputDelays: 0  (read-only)
    numLayerDelays: 0  (read-only)
```

And then you can access these properties like this:

```
net.numInputs
```

And if you want to see the methods available for that variable, you can do

```
methods(net)
```